An English equivalent of the Japanese idiom "be tied with a red string (of destiny)"

Yumi: I heard Akira and Yukiko got married last month. Is that true?
Saki: Yup. They were tied with a red string (of destiny).

This is a word-for-word translation from Japanese into English. The bold part means that they were destined to get married.
Is there an English idiomatic phrase similar to "be tied with a red string of destiny"? If not, is there an English idiom that means "be destined to get married"?

We often say that a couple were 'made for each other'.

The red string is an element (either symbolic or fantastical) that shows up in English-language media sometimes, but I don't think I'd understand it if you tried to use it as an idiom.

I don't know the details, but I believe that in some cultures, part of the wedding ceremony involves symbolically tying the bride and groom's wrists together. Could this  be the case here?

Another possibility is one that alludes to astrology:

Mike: I heard Bill and Alice got married last month.
Joe: Yeah. It was written in the stars. LOL


This was the first one I thought of. See also the inverse, a quotation from Shakespeare's Romeo and Juliet, "star-crossed lovers."

As mentioned previously by others here "to be made/meant for each other" is one expression that is possible here.
Another similar idiom is to say that something is:

A match made in heaven

For example

Harry and Sally just got married! It's a match made in heaven.

Note: this idiom can be used in other contexts, not just marriage. It can be used for any two things which go together well or were meant to be together.

"match made in heaven" means the people are perfectly suited for each other. That doesn't mean they were destined to find each other -- that's serendipity.

Depends how you look at it.  There's an implied literal meaning too; that the match was created in heaven (by god/s presumably), which would suggest something destined to be.

We could consider destined (or fated) to be together, or made (meant or destined) for each other.
They were destined to be together.

Considering how widespread the trope is in anime, and how terminally otaku much of the Anglophone world is, I don't see any problem with the idiom as is, although "Red String of Fate" might be more common.

Not that many Americans are familiar with anime. What does "otaku" mean, is that also something only a Japanophile would know?

Not just anime. The game Scarlet Nexus heavily relies on the red string of fate. Both stylistically and for its plot.

An "otaku" is the "36 year old neckbeard in his mom's basement" trope. Many people say it about themselves proudly so it isn't really a slur but it is a (young) person who is obsessed with nerdish or pop-culture stuff to the detriment of their social skills.

@Barmar I used it to mean "lover of anime". There's also "weeaboo" or "weeb". "Japanophile" is deprecated, much like "Japanimation"

None of those are well-known English terms, AFAIK. In fact, I wouldn't be surprised if less than 50% of Americans even know what anime is. What's the non-deprecated word for "enthusiast about Japanese culture", analogous to francophile and anglophile?
